# What is CPS file (Card Personalisation Specification)?

Tags: smartcard, javacard

Can anybody explain in detail what is CPS file?Why do we require it? etc

Comment: Whats left unclear [here](https://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=20)?

Comment: Adding to above...can you also explain difference between card personalisation and application personalisation?

Answer (score 1):

Card personalization is one of the major components in the production of the EMV cards. Numerous methods of personalization with proprietary commands exist for each card or application. For Card personalization, basic EMV applications should be present on the card.This is sometimes is referred to as "on-card" personalization.

It would be helpful if you elaborate what exactly you want to understand because EMV CPS is a very wide topic, it is like you are asking what is Global Platform.

Comment: I'm not talking about EMV card. I'm talking in general about all smart cards.Still thanks for clarifying.